# N+1 when trying to eager load more than 1 relationship deep. Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Not sure if my title is correct for my situation but...

In my Laravel project I'm trying to display an Image with all the comments that belong to that image. Each comment has likes. When I try to eager load this I'm still getting a query for each comment fetching the likes for that comment. Is there a way I can eager load the likes for every comment that is being eager loaded?

Here are my models

Media Model

```
class Media extends Eloquent {
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}
```

Comment Model

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {
    public function media()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Media');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Like');
    }
}
```

Like Model

```
class Like extends Eloquent {
    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Comment');
    }
}
```

My controller

```
public function imageViewer($id)
{
    $images = Media::with(['comments', 'comments.likes'])->where('resource_id', $id)->simplePaginate(1);
    return View::make('image-viewer', compact('images'));
}
```

I know that if I want to eager load the comments for an image I can do something like this
`Media::with('comments')->get();`

but I'm not sure how I can then eager load the likes that belong to those Media Comments that I just eager loaded?

Comment: Please tag yor question with proper Laravel version.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this.

```
$medias = Media::with(['comments' => function($query) {
    $query->with('likes');
}])->where('resource_id', $id)->simplePaginate(1);
```

And you can retrieve likes for each comments.

```
foreach($medias as $media)
{
    echo $media->name; // column
    foreach($media->comments as $comment)
    {
        echo $comment->likes()->count();
    }
}
```